# How to allocate x copy of n objects among k persons

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have following use case;

I have N distinct items , each can have x number of copies. Now I need to distribute these items among k persons where each person's capacity is varying and can be <=N.

Following conditions must be met;

Each person should get one and only one copy of an Item

Example:

```
Items = apple , banana , orange
copies = 3 ( It means we have 3 apples , 3 bananas and 3 oranges )
So I have a array;
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} // 1,2,3 = 3 apples ; 4,5,6 = 3 banana ; 7,8,9 = 3 oranges
Total Person = 5
Person     Capacity
P1         3
P2         2
P3         1
P4         1
P5         2
```

How can I solve such problem ? The problem I am facing is that when I allocate it for an arbitrary numbers for N , x , k , I sometimes end up in a case where I am left with some items to allocate because I can't ensure the condition that "Each person should get one and only one copy of an Item"

Comment: Can't your problem just be solved greedily ?

Comment: I have tried greedy approach but I end up a case where I am left with items to allocate but can’t because of the constraint that no person should get same item twice. I also thought it’s a trivial problem but greedy approach is not working.

Comment: Did your greedy approach include handling persons with largest capacity first? That should be sufficient to find all solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each item has the same "weight", you can actually solve this problem greedily. To ensure that each person receives distinct items, we create the sequence containing all the `xN` items by repeating the sequence of `N` distinct items `x` times. Then, we go through each of the persons and simply remove and assign them the first `c` items of this sequence, where `c` is that person's carrying capacity.

This works because of the way we have laid out the items and because `c <= N`. In our "mega" sequence, duplicates are always `N` indices away from each other, so `c` consecutive elements will never contain two duplicates. Duplicates will only appear in contiguous subsequences containing more than `N` items.

Note that in the implementation of this algorithm, you don't actually have to create the mega sequence; you can simply repeatedly iterate through the distinct item sequence by using modular arithmetic. To keep the explanation simple, I will be forming the "mega" items sequence in the examples, but you don't have to do this in the implementation.

Taking the example in your question, let the 3 distinct items be `A, B, C` with 3 copies each. The "mega" sequence is formed by repeating the distinct items sequence 3 times: `A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C`. Now we go through each person and simply assign them the number of items they can carry. To illustrate this, consider the following cases for the capacity array (taken from your question and comments below):

- `[3, 2, 1, 1, 2]`: P1 gets `A, B, C`, P2 gets `A, B`, P3 gets `C`, P4 gets `A`, and P5 gets `B, C`.
- `[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]`: P1 gets `A, B`, P2 gets `C, A`, P3 gets `B, C`, P4 gets `A, B`, and P5 gets `C`.
- `[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]`: P1 gets `A, B, C`, P2 gets `A`, P3 gets `B`, P4 gets `C`, P5 gets `A`, P6 gets `B, C`.

Comment: Greedy approach didn’t work that’s why I had to post this question here to get some insight.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the case(s) that fail for you? Unless I'm missing something, this solution should work for all cases (provided that there is enough total capacity to allocate all items of course).

Comment: For example I have 3 items and 3 copies of each; My array is like items [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} // 1,2,3 - Item1 ; 4,5,6 - Item2; 7,8,9 - item3. Now I have 5 users with capacity as U1 : 2 ; U2: 2 ; U3: 2 ; U4: 2 ; U5: 1; Now I go in loop for each item and user and I assign U1 = {1,4} ; U2={2, 5} ; U3={3, 6} ; Now I am left with item 7 , 8 ,9  which are same copy of item 3. so I can't allocate 2 items to U4 as I can't  assign same item to a user twice. So greedy approach doesn't work for all cases.

Comment: Another case with same item set and copies  item [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ; Suppose the User capacity is : U1 = 3 ; U2 = 1 ; U3=1 ; U4 = 1 ; U5 = 1 ; U6=2; Now if I loop through each item and assign to each user; U1 = 1 ; U2=2 ; U3=3 ; U4=4 ; U5= 5 ; U6 = 6 ;  U1 = 7 ; U6 = 8; Now U1 can't be assigned 9 as it already has 7 (7 and 9 belong to same item)

Comment: @Bankelaal the greedy approach I outline is different from the one you are using and should work for the two cases you specified. The items array is generated as `[A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C]` rather than `[A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C]` (which is what you are using). I've edited my answer to include examples, which hopefully should clarify this further.

Comment: EvilTak, thanks yes it worked , Although I made the sequence like [A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C] and greedy can work. Although I have one more case. Where If I have to take out some of the items from a User and assign to another user , the users could be existing user or a new , what strategy I can use to make sure the constraints are honored. I can only redistribute those items which are not  eaten yet. For example if U1 had 3 items and he ate 2 of them and 1 is pending I can reassign to another user.